# Rails4 + Paperclip (unable to clone from model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

Using Rails 4.0.2 and paperclip 3.5.3

I want to be able to clone the same model (Event) for any given dates that the user puts in the form. So if I want to have events day x, x+1 and x+2, I'll need to copy the paperclip attachment (which happens to be an image) over to the x+1 and x+2 events.

In theory, it should be enough to do something along the lines of

```
def create

respond_to do |format|
  if @event.save
     dates.each do |date| #the date var comes from another place, redacted for clearness
       event = @event.dup
       event.photo = @eevnt.photo
       event.save
     end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't.

It somehow marks the paperclip attachments for deletion.

Here's a copy of the log:

> Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"U9H0RPuSKd1NgjMsoqHCAUqNW+IrWtZZM9PtzGAefTA=", "event"=>{"title"=>"fecha", "event_type"=>"conciertos", "province"=>"Madrid", "city"=>"Madrid", "replication_dates"=>"30/01/2014,31/01/2014", "time_template_hour"=>"12", "time_template_minute"=>"0", "location_name"=>"Sala Lapusuvi", "address"=>"Cl. albasanz 72", "description"=>"
>
> lorem
>
> \r\n", "photo"=>#, @original_filename="_MG_4256.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"event[photo]\"; filename=\"_MG_4256.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "youtube_video"=>"", "event_tickets_attributes"=>{"1390997939186"=>{"name"=>"General", "price"=>"10", "stock"=>"10", "_destroy"=>"false"}}, "fee_handler"=>"0", "no_print_event"=>"0", "terms"=>"1", "status"=>""}, "commit"=>"Crear mi evento"}
>     Promoter Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "promoters".* FROM "promoters" WHERE "promoters"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "promoters"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
>   Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: convert '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "250" '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg20140129-1873-1ng5mxd'
>   Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg20140129-1873-1ng5mxd'
>   Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: convert '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x300" -crop "300x300+75+0" +repage '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg20140129-1873-1elyw4x'
>   Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg20140129-1873-1elyw4x'
>   Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: convert '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x100" -crop "100x100+25+0" +repage '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg20140129-1873-1uzuzbr'
>   Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-ye9lkg20140129-1873-1uzuzbr'
>      (0.2ms)  begin transaction
>   DBG: TERMS => "1"
>     Event Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."title" = 'fecha' AND "events"."timeline" = '2014-01-30 11:00:00.000000') LIMIT 1
>   Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `photo_content_type`
>     SQL (1.2ms)  INSERT INTO "events" ("address", "city", "created_at", "description", "event_type", "fee_handler", "location_name", "photo_content_type", "photo_file_name", "photo_file_size", "photo_updated_at", "promoter_id", "province", "timeline", "title", "updated_at", "youtube_video") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["address", "Cl. albasanz 72"], ["city", "Madrid"], ["created_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:17 CET +01:00], ["description", "
>
> lorem
>
> \r\n"], ["event_type", "conciertos"], ["fee_handler", 0], ["location_name", "Sala Lapusuvi"], ["photo_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["photo_file_name", "_MG_4256.jpg"], ["photo_file_size", 360091], ["photo_updated_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:16 CET +01:00], ["promoter_id", 2], ["province", "Madrid"], ["timeline", Thu, 30 Jan 2014 12:00:00 CET +01:00], ["title", "fecha"], ["updated_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:17 CET +01:00], ["youtube_video", ""]]
>     SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "event_tickets" ("created_at", "event_id", "name", "price", "stock", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:17 CET +01:00], ["event_id", 98], ["name", "General"], ["price", 10.0], ["stock", 10], ["updated_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:17 CET +01:00]]
>      (24.6ms)  commit transaction
>     EventTicket Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "event_tickets".* FROM "event_tickets" WHERE "event_tickets"."event_id" = ?  [["event_id", 98]]
>   Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: convert '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "250" '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y820140129-1873-1jxdah6'
>   Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y820140129-1873-1jxdah6'
>   Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: convert '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x300" -crop "300x300+75+0" +repage '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y820140129-1873-1uq5p2o'
>   Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y820140129-1873-1uq5p2o'
>   Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]'
>   Command :: convert '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y8.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x100" -crop "100x100+25+0" +repage '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y820140129-1873-q03px0'
>   Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/q1/txykj42x56g0v_4pfn_3fs0r0000gn/T/_MG_425620140129-1873-azu3y820140129-1873-q03px0'
>      (0.2ms)  begin transaction
>   DBG: TERMS => "1"
>     Event Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "events" WHERE ("events"."title" = 'fecha' AND "events"."timeline" = '2014-01-31 11:00:00.000000') LIMIT 1
>   Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `photo_content_type`
>     SQL (1.4ms)  INSERT INTO "events" ("address", "city", "created_at", "description", "event_type", "fee_handler", "location_name", "photo_content_type", "photo_file_name", "photo_file_size", "photo_updated_at", "promoter_id", "province", "timeline", "title", "updated_at", "youtube_video") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["address", "Cl. albasanz 72"], ["city", "Madrid"], ["created_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:18 CET +01:00], ["description", "
>
> lorem
>
> \r\n"], ["event_type", "conciertos"], ["fee_handler", 0], ["location_name", "Sala Lapusuvi"], ["photo_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["photo_file_name", "_MG_4256.jpg"], ["photo_file_size", 360091], ["photo_updated_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:16 CET +01:00], ["promoter_id", 2], ["province", "Madrid"], ["timeline", Fri, 31 Jan 2014 12:00:00 CET +01:00], ["title", "fecha"], ["updated_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:18 CET +01:00], ["youtube_video", ""]]
>     SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "event_tickets" ("created_at", "event_id", "name", "price", "stock", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:18 CET +01:00], ["event_id", 99], ["name", "General"], ["price", 10.0], ["stock", 10], ["updated_at", Wed, 29 Jan 2014 13:37:18 CET +01:00]]
>   [paperclip] deleting /Users/fxjade/Documents/company/app/public/system/events/photos/000/000/098/original/_MG_4256.jpg
>   [paperclip] deleting /Users/fxjade/Documents/company/app/public/system/events/photos/000/000/098/buy/_MG_4256.jpg
>   [paperclip] deleting /Users/fxjade/Documents/company/app/public/system/events/photos/000/000/098/medium/_MG_4256.jpg
>   [paperclip] deleting /Users/fxjade/Documents/company/app/public/system/events/photos/000/000/098/thumb/_MG_4256.jpg
>      (18.1ms)  commit transaction
>     Rendered promoter_mailer/event_created_email.html.erb (0.9ms)

Has this happened to anyone before?

Any input on why doing it from the console works but I can't pull the-**same**-stunt from a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Event.new instead of @event.dup ?
Something along the lines of:

```
event = Event.new(@vent.attributes.except('id', 'photo_file_name', 'photo_content_type', 'photo_file_size', 'photo_updated_at')) # And any other attribute you don't want to copy
event.photo = @event.photo
event.save
```

Comment: Well... that was easy... I thought I had tried that, but it seems I forgot about it. Works like a charm. Thanks! Though I'm still curious as to why the dup thing worked from the IRB console...